# how to find and replace with sed

Tags: sed

have heard a lot about SED and downloaded and installed GNU SED for my Windows XP. 1) The install program installed it c:\program files. 2) I have a file in directory C:\lewisC\bm_pg0001.txt. The file has text, 1.pdf in it. 3) I want to change 1.pdf to bm_pg0001.pdf
4) after messing around to invoke SED with paths etc. I copied all the files in sed bin folder to C:\lewisC\ used command here for DOS prompt and finally able to invoke SED.

Now can somebody help with the sed command to change 1.pdf to bm_pg0001.pdf in the file bm_pg0001.txt. Thanks- I now realize why Windows was a success. Thanks

Comment: In case you hear about "coreutils" "grep" or "awk" in the future I suggest this:  (http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

`sed "s/1\.pdf/bm_pg0001.pdf/g" < input_file > output_file`

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems Windows is a better platform for those unwilling to do even the most basic research. Take a look at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html.

Comment: sed "/11 0 obj/,/endobj/ s/.*//" <bm_lewisC_0221.pdf -b>jk2.pdf -b

Comment: yes! yes! and yes! I almost lost my mind trying basic research - SED is STRUGGLE Ends in Diamonds and this the only liner I wanted and got Thanks a lot to all the gurus and BEN GRAHAM - sed "/11 0 obj/,/endobj/ s/.*//" <bm_lewisC_0221.pdf -b>jk2.pdf -b I can now edit any pdf file the way I want.